# AWS restrict end user to connect to my instance from SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, private-key

For AWS, when generate an instance you can either generate a new .pem or use previous .pem.

But how can i restrict that **only me** can connect to the instance through SSH. I know that I can set up security group and set inbound rules to allow only my IP address to do SSH. However, whoever has my private key can still SSH my instance. So what exactly does the security group restrict?

I am now using Windows 7 and putty to connect to my instance through SSH, it seems like the only way that I can connect to my instance is by using the .ppk file. Or maybe this is a question for using terminal to SSH the instance?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1):

This topic is unrelated to Amazon EC2. It is purely a Linux configuration, the same as any Linux computer.

When you SSH to a Linux computer, you provide a private key. The server will look in the `/home/<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys` file to find a matching public key. If the keys match, then the SSH session is permitted.

You can add add/remove keys in that file.

If you wish to be the only person who can SSH into the server, then:

- Create a new keypair
- Put the public half of the keypair in `/home/<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- Remove any other keys from that file
- Repeat for all users you have defined on the server

By default, EC2 creates the `ec2-user`, so if you haven't created any more users, you will only need to edit: `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: So what does the inbound rules actually restrict when i set the source from my ip address?

Comment: Security Groups control network traffic. You would need to configure a Security Group associated with the instance to permit Inbound traffic on port 22 (SSH) from an IP address range that includes your address (which could be _only_ your IP address up to the whole Internet). However, this only controls network traffic. It has no concept of **who** is trying to access. You can certainly use the Security Group to restrict access to only your IP address, but anyone on that IP address could then communicate with the instance (eg your office or household). To control personal access, use a SSH key.

Comment: I looked into this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html which basically shows how to manage the user accounts. So if i want multiple users to access my instance, am i supposed to create private key for each of them or let them use the same key as I am using?

Comment: The best practice is for each user to create their own key, and then give you the public half of the key to put in their `authorized_keys` file. This way, even _you_ cannot login as them, since you do not have their private key. However, if your users are less-technical, you could create the keys for them. You certainly should _not_ have them all use the same key, because that means they could login as any other user. Think of the key as a password, except that it is so big that it is kept in a file. Don't give multiple users the same password.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a rule in the security groups to restrict access to you instance is essential.
This way not the whole internet can try to access the instance.

But you are right. You can still login with the SSH-Private-Key and have full access.

To avoid this you can remove rights from the login user and transfer this rights to another user.

So you can login but you cannot do anything and need to change user first.

```
su privileged
```

The privileged user is secured by another password you need to know.
That way you should have pretty solid access control.

I hope that helps!

Dominik

Comment: what do u mean by transfer the rights to another user? Shouldn't there be a superadmin and rest are just normal users?